# HDD randomly reconnects

Tags: windows, hard-drive, sata

So my hdd started to reconnect itself randomly once in a minute or so. I decided, that its time has come, and bought another one. 2 months passed, and this all started again with a new one. My OS is on ssd and it works perfectly fine in any sata slot, but hard drives fail. I even tried to connect it with usb-sata cable, but got the same results with 3 different hdds. Its not the voltage problem, because I used an external adapter for usb connection, smarts are fine too. What could be the reason for this?

Specs:

Win 7 64

Asus p6t deluxe v2

i7 920 (Bloomfield)

ssd: samsung EVO 850

hdds: wd1500hlfs, st1000dm010 (barracuda)

AHCI mode

Comment: Have you tried replacing the SATA cable?

Comment: @patkim ye, i tried